# Android: Custom spinner help

Tags: android, spinner

I am following [this](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57) tutorial on how to create custom spinners. Near the begining it instructs you to navigate to: *android.jar\res\drawable-finger* But for some reason I can't find the "drawable-finger" folder in my android.jar. I thought it may have to do with the API level so I changed it from 1.6 to 2.1 to no avail. I went around this and put them in the drawable folder thinking I could just work around it but then the spinner has the image stretched and malformed instead of repeating the image in the x direction. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the code
Spinner

```
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/catspinner" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:background="@drawable/spinnerbackground"/>
```

code for the spinner background:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_select" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_press" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_normal" />
</selector>
```

it looks like this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sherif is correct. As far as following the tutorial, it doesn't (and shouldn't) suggest that you put the images back in `android.jar/res/drawable-finger`. You should put your versions of those images in your `drawable` folders (i.e. `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, etc).

I suspect that the issue with the image being stretched and not repeated is a result of your code or image, not the location you put the images. You could post your code and we might be able to help with that.

I also noticed that the tutorial looks like it is based off of a pre-release Android SDK version. I'm guessing that the `drawable-finger` folder no longer exists. It's also possible that other elements of the tutorial are outdated.

Comment: Looks like it might be a problem with your 9 patch. You might want to post that too.

Comment: Hmm good possibility because I'm not sure what that is :). Could you explain it? I had originally taken the .9 extension off the example files, I redownloaded them and left the .9 extension on but now I have a series of errors stating that the "No resource found". I tried a clean and tried adding .9 to background xml with no success

Comment: Nine patch images are a way to define a single image file that can stretch to any size without being distorted. If you're not familiar with them, start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: Do you know why eclipse is giving me an error when adding nine-patch files? I add as file.9.png and it gives me an error (but it doesn't show in the error log whats wrong)